# Layer rule for all pages except two in Orchard CMS

Tags: widget, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I am trying to create a layer rule in the widgets section that shows a widget on all pages except two (or more). I've tried a number of options, in some cases the rule will exclude one page but not the other, in other cases it does not exclude either.

At first I wasn't sure how the exclude would work, I tried `true not url("/page-1")` which returned the error "The rule is not valid: Syntax error: Unexpected token in primary expression (Token &#39;Not&#39; at position 5)", so I switched to `not url("/page-1")` which works (for excluding just one page).

I tried a number of ways to exclude more than one page without any luck, including these:

```
not url("/page-1") or not url("/page-2") // not excluded on any pages
not url("/page-1") or (not url("/page-2")) // not excluded on any pages
not url("/page-1") or url("/page-2") // excluded on page-1 only
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/1067) which confirmed that `url("/foo") or url("/bar")` is how you include two URLs, which would suggest that the first example above is at least close.

Is it possible to show a widget on all pages, with a few specific pages excluded? Also, either way, is there a different method recommended for doing something like this, other than using a widget layer rule?

Comment: I wanted to do something very similar and ended up writing a condition so that I could include/exclude pages from a layer based on a tag, i.e. have a layer rule of `tag("name of tag")`. I've uploaded the module to the modules gallery (https://gallery.orchardproject.net/Packages/RW.Orchard.Conditions) should it be of use to you =) and blogged about how I put it together as well (http://robertwray.co.uk/blog/writing-a-custom-condition-for-orchard-checking-the-tags-on-a-page-published-to-github-and-the-orchard-gallery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
not (url("/page-1") or url("/page-2"))
```

I'm chalking this one up to being a little out of practice with logical expressions.